# Changing scheduler tick time

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I want to change the scheduler tcik time(The amount of time CPU spends on each process). 
Initially I checked about jiffies, jiffies variable represents the no.of timer ticks from the boot. CONFIG_HZ in the configuration file represents no.of timer ticks per second, please correct me if this is not correct.

The CONFIG_HZ value is same as scheduler tick time ? if it is different then please guide me where I can change the scheduler tick time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes CONFIG_HZ defines the number of ticks in one second.
Basically scheduler is invoked every 1/CONFIG_HZ second for taking waking, task sleeping, balance load.

scheduler_tick -> This function gets called every 1/CONFIG_HZ second.
CONFIG_HZ defined in Kconfig and its value is set using .config which can be modified using menuconfig.

Global Variable jiffies holds the number of ticks that have occurred since the system has booted.

Answer (score 0):

I d like to clarify about terms.

Jiffies is  strictly speaking a measure of time.
Like we have hours , minutes, seconds exactly the same thing 
is jiffy. And only after that it happens so that kernel works 
with time via jiffy units.

It happens so that scheduler is launched every jiffy (roughly
speaking). to get more details i suggest to look at "linux kernel development" book. - https://github.com/eeeyes/My-Lib-Books/blob/master/Linux%20Kernel%20Development%2C%203rd%20Edition.pdf